# Send HTTP request from Arduino UNO+ESP8266

Tags: serial, esp8266, http, espressif

I am trying to send an HTTP request from from an Arduino UNO through an ESP-01 connected by Serial.
Communication with the ESP and connection to the AP work fine. But when i try to send an HTTP request to a server, it fails with a strange response from the ESP:

[image: Serial output]

What are those strange characters coming from the ESP ?

(Note that other characters are mistaken as well, like the "http://xxx.col" instead of "http://xxx.com")
Here is the code I am using:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define RX 10
#define TX 11
String AP = "xxx";
String PASS = "xxx";
String HOST = "\"http://xxx.com\"";
String PORT = "80";
String tcp = "\"TCP\"";
String field = "field1";
int countTrueCommand;
int countTimeCommand; 
boolean found = false; 
int valSensor = 1;
SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX); 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  sendCommand("AT",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\""+ AP +"\",\""+ PASS +"\"",20,"OK");
}
void loop() {
 sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK");
 //String connection = "AT+CIPSTART="+ tcp +"," + remoteip + "," + portnum + "\r\n");

 String getData = "GET battery/add.php?RAWVOLT=99&VOLT=99&RAWCURR=99 HTTP/1.0\r\n"; //this is mockup data for testing purpose
 getData += "Host: xxx.000webhostapp.com\r\n"; // add the required header
 getData += "\r\n";

 sendData("AT+CIPSTART="+ tcp +"," + HOST + "," + PORT + "\r\n",150000,true);
 sendData("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4000,true);

 //sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">");
 esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++;
 sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK");
}



 void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {
   ***similar to sendData below***
 }


 String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    String response = ""; // ESP8266 sendData String
    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {
        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
        response+=c;
      }  
    }

    if(debug)
    {
      Serial.print(response);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: use the WiFiEsp library

Comment: the hostname can't contain http://

Comment: You can't use SoftwareSerial at 115200 baud. The Arduino is not fast enough to keep up. Either switch to a board with a spare hardware UART or work out how to safely change the baud rate on your version of the ESP-01 to 9600.

Comment: @Juraj thanks, i removed the http://

Comment: @Majenko I changed to 9600 baud rate, still having the same issue :
`AT+CIPST@RT="TCP","app.⸮Kѡ⸮ͅ⸮⸮⸮嵅⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮b⸮⸮j

ERROR
`

Comment: did you change the baud rate of the AT firmware with AT+UART command?

Comment: When I try with the AT command, it fails: `1. at command => AT+UART=9600 Fail
`

Comment: `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0`. send it at 115200 baud. the AT firmware will remember it as default. then switch the SoftwareSerial to 9600 baud

Comment: @Juraj: Same response as before: `0. at command => AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0 Fail
`

Comment: what is `0. at command =>`?

Comment: it's nothing, just a comment to make the output easier to read. Basically the ESP fails to execute the AT command.

Comment: the response to AT+UART is not important. was it applied? btw. you have CIPMUX but you don't specify linkId with CIPSTART